# Infeasible row in objective function cplex

Tags: cplex, opl

I am working on a min problem. When I run it in cplex, I am getting infeasibility and it tells me the row number causing infeasibility. However, this row corresponds somewhere in the objective function. The inf. row in the objective function is:

- 581.876999999999 s#563#3 + 561.177 s#563#4 + 540.477 s#563#5

I checked the related constraint and variable: The variable s_m,d is a ratio of material m will be delivered to the depot d. So, the sum of the ratio must be 1. So the constraint is like that:

```
    forall(m in mm)
 {    
    sum(d in D)s[m][d]==1;
 }
```

What can cause this infeasibility and how can I correct it? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

In order to get more info about infeasibility in OPL you can label constraints and turn

```
forall(m in mm)
 {    
    sum(d in D)s[m][d]==1;
 }
```

into

```
forall(m in mm)
 {    
    ctName:sum(d in D)s[m][d]==1;
 }
```

In [Simple Optimization](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-decision-optimization-simple-alex-fleischer/) see [Conflicts and relaxations](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zooconflictandrelaxation.mod)

Comment: Thank you so much @Alex Fleischer.  I can see the constraint causing infeasibility now but cplex tells me that it is infeasible but goes on solving :Row 'const3(1)' infeasible, all entries at implied bounds.
Presolve time = 0,01 sec. (7,22 ticks)
Found incumbent of value 2053,000000 after 0,11 sec. (31,41 ticks)
Warning:  Non-integral bounds for integer variables rounded.
Tried aggregator 2 times...... and starts optimization. So, when I try to write conflicts and relaxations. It does  not work, because cplex solves . What can I do now?